# не выходит вставить хтмл строку с скоупа в хтмл, чтобы теги срабатывали

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Не вышло сформировать четко и внятно суть проблемы, наверное по этому я в гугле и не смог найти более менее похожий вопрос, к сожалению. Есть приложение на ангуляре, в скоуп я получаю ответ с сервера - уже отформатированный шаблон хтмл, который соответственно получен (и храниться) как строка. Пробовал по простому - просто выполнить в хтмл {{скоуп}}, но он вставляет его как строку и теги в том числе. Пробовал еще 1 вариант с angular-sanitize, который вроде должен переобразовать в текст с обработкой тегов, но тоже без результатно..

```
app.controller('Controller', function($scope) {
  $scope.text = "<!doctype html><html lang='en'><head><meta charset='UTF-8'><title>Document</title></head><body><h1>Hello world</h1></body></html>"
})
```

Пример [в plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/pdd0KKnZsFlfRWVBKJqM?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае можно воспользоваться  [директивой `ng-bind-html`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) и [сервисом `$sce`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('Controller', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.text = $sce.trustAsHtml("<h1>Hello world</h1>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<span ng-app="App" ng-controller="Controller" data-ng-bind-html="text"></span>
```

Либо [модулем `ngSanitize`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize)

```js
var app = angular.module('App', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('Controller', function($scope) {
  $scope.text = "<h1>Hello world</h1>";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<span ng-app="App" ng-controller="Controller" data-ng-bind-html="text"></span>
```

Comment: пробовал ngSanitize, но оно не сработало тк я не правильно передавал данные в хтмл, спасибо большое!

Comment: Ох уж эти фреймворки